# Problem with declaring List<myClass> property in VS2010

Tags: c#, list, properties

Hi
I created two usercontrol (the line & the station) and use the STATION in THE LINE usercontrol and finally i use the "LINE" usercontrol in some forms.

There is no problem at design time, but whem i want to add "Line" usercontrol to form.
In this case, visual studio stop working and then closed.

I comment some changes in my code and find that problem is from property about number of stations in  line. whem  i comment it every thing go ok but i need this property.
this is my code

```
[Serializable]
public class ActionPoint
{
    public string CarInfo;
    public string RightStationName;
    public string RightStationInfo;
    public string LeftStationName;
    public string LeftStationInfo;

    public ActionPoint()
    {
    }
}
```

and use this class in my property. I use this property to define stations in line.

```
public class Line : UserControl
{ 
   public List<ActionPoint> Stations
   {
   get { return Stations; }
   set { Stations = value; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with property, not list, try this.

```
List<ActionPoint> _Stations;
public List<ActionPoint> Stations
{
   get { return _Stations; }
   set { _Stations = value; }
}
```

or

```
public List<ActionPoint> Stations
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Comment: I would replace `_Stations` by `_station` or just `stations` ;)

Comment: @Oscar meh, any naming convention is largely fine for a private field. Each to their own there...

Comment: @Marc Just kidding. See the smiley at the end ;)

Answer (score 4):

That code is recursive (when you try to get or set that property it goes on forever - follow the code...); the IDE is *probably* trying to either display that in a property-grid, or write code for the designer.cs - and is hitting your friendly stack-overflow exception.

As appropriate implementation would be:

```
private List<ActionPoint> stations = new List<ActionPoint>();
public List<ActionPoint> Stations { get { return stations; } }
```

Comment: Moreover, you can use a shorthand version of property definition,i-e  public List<ActionPoint> Stations { get ; }

Comment: @Furqan no you can't - that won't compile (no `set`). And even if it did, it wouldn't cause the (expected) field initialisation.

Comment: I hoped you had guessed to include the "set;" in shorthand property if you need it.

Comment: @Furqan "if I need it" - huh? it isn't up to me... and compiler rules aside, that still wouldn't address the (very deliberate) field initialisation.